# External user not able to login through Ranger Admin UI

Tags: apache-ranger

We are trying to implement Ranger admin UI authentication by using LDAP

We configured Open source Apache Ranger Admin UI and we are able to login into admin UI  via internal users - users created within admin UI (users created manually and users created by default). We also installed and configured the ranger user sync plugin and configured this with OpenLDAP. The user sync plugin is able to sync all users from OpenLDAP.

But the external users who got synced with open LDAP are not able to log in to Ranger Admin UI

Configured below properties in the admin install.properties file.

```
authentication_method=LDAP
xa_ldap_url=ldap://<IP address of open ldap>:<LDAP server port>
xa_ldap_base_dn=dc=example,dc=org
xa_ldap_bind_dn=cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org
xa_ldap_bind_password=<password>
xa_ldap_referral=follow
```

Answer (score 0):

@Shailendra The users synced back to Ranger from OpenLdap need to be modified with ADMIN status to be able to get into the Ranger Admin UI.  Login with a qualified Ranger Admin Account, go to Manage Users, find the user(s) you synced, edit the user, and set them to admin.  Then test login again.

Comment: I did change the user role to admin and still not able to log in. When I created a user on an open LDAP server using the LDIF file, I am providing a user password. My LDIF file looks as below

dn: cn=client3,dc=example,dc=org
uid: client3
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
givenName: tony
sn: Kumar
cn: client3
mail: ram@jimdo2.com
userPassword: <password>

When I tried to login as above uid and userPassword, I am not able to log in.

Comment: Have you validated any ldap login works?   If you do not have the LDAP settings for ambari, or ranger correct, it may sync the users, but not let them login.  This usually indicates you have the wrong setting values matching the username properly.   I always complete ambari user/group sync, and test logging into ambari with the sync users.  This exposes all the required settings for ranger too.